# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and IGNORE in one query

Tags: mysql

Ik execute a query that inserts some values in de table, if a combination of ID, Year, rownum (unique index) exists that i do a regular ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and so the row is updated. The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO data_advertenties_prijzen (`ID`, `year`, `rownum`, `status_prijs`,
    `datum_dag`, `timestamp_dag`) 
VALUES (100,2014,1,1,'2014-01-01',1388534400),
       (100,2014,2,1,'2014-07-16',1405468800),
       (100,2014,3,1,'2014-07-26',1406332800)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    status_prijs = VALUES(status_prijs), 
    datum_dag = VALUES(datum_dag), 
    timestamp_dag = VALUES(timestamp_dag)
```

Nothing difficults there, but….

I also want to do a ON DUPLICATE IGNORE for 1 value in the same query. I Also want to insert one row for 2015. For example: (100,2015,1,1,'2015-01-01',1405468800)…
If there is already a row with ID=100, Year=2015 And rownum=1 the insert of that row must be ignored.

How to do that?

Comment: On Duplicate works by checking primary and unique keys.  So you would need to set the columns `year` and `rownum` as unique keys for this to work.

Comment: James i did and the first query works fine, but i also want to insert a row with 2015 (year) but when there already is a row with 2015 than only the 2015 row must not be inserted...

Comment: Is there any reason not to set the year column as unique also?

Comment: Yes, there can be more rows with year 2014 (same for 2015)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the values conditionally in the ON DUPLICATE clause.

I did this experiment to make sure it works:

```
INSERT INTO data_advertenties_prijzen VALUES (100, 2014, 1, 7, now(), 1406332800)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    status_prijs = IF((id,year,rownum)=(100,2015,1), status_prijs, VALUES(status_prijs)),
    datum_dag = IF((id,year,rownum)=(100,2015,1), datum_dag, VALUES(datum_dag)),
    timestamp_dag = IF((id,year,rownum)=(100,2015,1), timestamp_dag, VALUES(timestamp_dag));
```

So if I try to insert a specific trio of id/year/rownum, it just uses the existing value, else if it's some other id/year/rownum, it uses the VALUES I specify in the INSERT.

Unfortunately, you must repeat the expression for each column you want to update.

Comment: Thanks Bill, i am going to test it. But if i look at it a get the feeling that de update only is done when the year is 2015. I want to do the insert or update for the 2014 years and a insert for a 2015 year, if there is already a row with 2015 than there the 2015 row must not be inserted...

Comment: Please test it and see if my solution does what you need. If it doesn't, please edit your question above and show an example of what you want it to do, and what it does that is not what you expect.